# How to get count of each item in sqlite group by specific column

Tags: android, sqlite, count, group-by

suppose that I have an android sqlite database with person names and place
like :

**Names** | **country** | **age**

Sam  | Canada | 22

Sara | Brazil | 25

Jack | UK     | 20

Anna | Brazil | 29

Jessica | Uk | 20

Steve | UK | 31

Selena | Brazil | 20

Shaki | UK | 27

I want to have each each country with the number of person in it

**like this**

Uk 4

Brazil 3

Canada 1

how to query this ?!

I queried this

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null,KEY_CITY, null, null);
```

but it's just display the `DISTINCT country` without the count

**thanks**

Comment: I queried this
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null,KEY_CITY, null, null);


but it's just display the DISTINCT country without the count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]
                {
                   KEY_CITY
                }, KEY_CITY+ " = 'UK'", null, null, null, null);

int persons = cursor.getCount();
```

This will give the number of `UK` occurrences in the `KEY_CITY` column.

Comment: Can anyone help me make this answer better?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT country, COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE country IN ('UK', 'Brazil', 'Canada') GROUP BY country
```